# How to add a new EditText with separate row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have 24 EditTexts and I want to have one EditText in each  row.

**Note**: this code is working properly, but I want to add one EditText in one row.
I want to add one EditText per row.
Means I want to set 24 EditTexts in 24 separate rows, not 24 EditText in one row.

This is **lyt_listview_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/ res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is-**lyt_listview_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="15dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is -**ListviewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListviewActivity extends Activity {

private String[] arrText =
        new String[]{"Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4"
        ,"Text5","Text6","Text7","Text8","Text9","Text10"
        ,"Text11","Text12","Text13","Text14","Text15"
        ,"Text16","Text17","Text18","Text19","Text20"
        ,"Text21","Text22","Text23","Text24"};
private String[] arrTemp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.lyt_listview_activity) ;

    arrTemp = new String[arrText.length];

    MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new  MyListAdapter();
    ListView listView = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends  BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arrText != null &&  arrText.length != 0){
            return arrText.length;    
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrText[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View  convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //ViewHolder holder = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater =  ListviewActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_listview_list, null);
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);    

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ref = position;

        holder.textView1.setText(arrText[position]);
         holder.editText1.setText(arrTemp[position]);
         holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        EditText editText1;
        int ref;
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by one editText in one row? Is your current code not adding one EditText per row of your ListView?

Comment: Its work fine. But there is one edittext.and i have 24 edittext.

Comment: Its work fine. But there is one edittext in 24 row.and i have 24 edittext and i want to add 24 edittext in 24 row.

Comment: Like tis      row1=add edittext1,row2=add edittext2.

Comment: I Still don't understand what you want. Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: @rachit , now i update more detail.

Comment: You already have one EditText in each row... Why do you think you do not?

Comment: As per your code, the 24 Edit Texts are in 24 separate rows only, they are not in 1 row. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In `lyt_listview_list.xml` you only have one EditText.

Those are your rows, and therefore, there's only one EditText  (and a TextView) in each row

How many rows you see is determined by `getCount()`, and that's returning `arrText.length`, or 24.

As far as "adding another row". You can't add anything to an array. You need to use an Arraylist in your adapter. In which case, you'd likely want ArrayAdapter and not BaseAdapter